# Digest JSON message payload

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, webhooks

I'm not familiar to JSON and not sure if this is possible,

Background:
I'm using AWS cloudwatch and uses AWS SNS to send a HTTPS Endpoint which is Twilio. Notification are Good, Working as Expected in Hipchat, It was concise and summarize

```
[ALARM] saas-ajtest-mem-gt-80-5min Threshold Crossed: 2 datapoints [47.9 (07/08/17 01:10:00), 47.9 (07/08/17 01:05:00)] were greater than or equal to the threshold (30.0).
```

but when it was sent to my Twilio number, I will receive all the message way too long.

```
Type:  "Notification"
   MessageId" : "27684767-bf13-5e0f-b02d-15667f98e595"
 TopicArn:   "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:00000000:critical_twilio"
  Subject:   "ALARM: "saas-ajtest-mem-gt-80-5min" in US East (N. Virginia)"
   Message: {"AlarmName":"saas-ajtest-mem-gt-80-5min""AlarmDescription":null"AWSAccountId":"00000000""NewStateValue":"ALARM""NewStateReason":"Threshold Crossed: 2 datapoints [47.9 (07/08/17 01:10:00) 47.9 (07/08/17 01:05:00)] were greater than or equal to the threshold (30.0).""StateChangeTime":"2017-08-07T01:11:39.708+0000""Region":"US East (N. Virginia)""OldStateValue":"OK""Trigger":{"MetricName":"MemoryUtilization""Namespace":"test""StatisticType":"Statistic""Statistic":"AVERAGE""Unit":null"Dimensions":[{"name":"ContainerName""value":"ajtest"}]"Period":60"EvaluationPeriods":5"ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold""Threshold":30.0"TreatMissingData":"""EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile":""}}"
```

What I want to do is to  Get only the AlarmName, Threshold Crossed,Dimensions name. Basically I want a output similar to the hipchat.

```
This my sample groovy script

def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText( body )
def type = result.Type
def messageID = result.MessageId
def subject = result.Subject
def message = result.Message
def alldata = type + messageID + subject + message
```

Tried using

```
def message = result.Message.AlarmName
def message = result.Message."AlarmName"
```

But it will return null only.

Any Inputs will be appreciated. Thanking you ahead of time :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a solution, I've used map

```
Map<String, String> mappedResult = (Map<String, String>) slurper.parseText( message )
```

This will get the other json :)